# How to select new added elements with jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I have a selector to select all elements with rel="tooltip" attribute: `$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();`
But when I add new elements dynamically, for example using append() method ,it seems not working. How can I select that new ones ?

Comment: It works for only current elements in DOM. With new added elements, by append() method for example, it wont work. I want to know if there is somethings like on() method can apply to my case

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip()
```

This initializes the elements **currently** in the document.
You will need to call the function again to initialize new "tooltip" elements.

You can just add the same jquery snippet directly after you've added the new elements to the DOM, or bind and trigger events.

This really depends on how you plan to add the new tools tips to the page dynamically

Comment: So it seems like the last solution. I thought that somethings like on() method could solve my problem, so I tried to do all in one line of code. Anw, thank you very much